# @Scheduled behaviour when processing takes a long time. run in parallel?

Tags: java, spring, parallel-processing, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I have a method with @Scheduled and this is set to run every 10 secs like so:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000 * 10)
```

If the method takes more than 10 secs to process, will another execution start in parallel? or will it wait for the current execution to finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't, because [`fixedDelay`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#fixedDelay--) works like follows:

> Execute the annotated method with a fixed period in milliseconds
> between the end of the last invocation and the start of the next.

Meaning that it waits for the function to complete and then waits n-milliseconds until the function is invoked again.

Answer (score 1):

It will wait until previous execution is completed I was going through its doc and its written over there

> Execute the annotated method with a fixed period in milliseconds
> between the end of the last invocation and the start of the next.

Here is the [Spring Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#fixedDelay--) where I have seen it.